Number of inversions in an array. An inversion is a pair (i,j) which respects i<j with array[i]>array[j]
The problem I'm trying to solve is:
Let A[0...n - 1] be an array of n distinct positive integers. If i < j and A[i] > A[j] then the pair (i, j) is called an inversion of A. Given n and an array A your task is to find the number of inversions of A.
Input:
The first line contains t, the number of testcases followed by a blank space. Each of the t tests start with a number n (n <= 200000). Then n + 1 lines follow. In the ith line a number A[i - 1] is given (A[i - 1] <= 10^7). The (n + 1)th line is a blank space.
Output:
For every test output one line giving the number of inversions of A.
Example:
Input:
2
3
3
1
2
5
2
3
8
6
1
Output:
2
5
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
struct ordered_multiset {
    int len = 0;
    const int ADD = 1000010;
    const int MAXVAL = 1000000010;
    unordered_map<int, int> mp;
    tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> T;
    inline void insert(int x){
        len++, x += MAXVAL;
        int c = mp[x]++;
        T.insert((x * ADD) + c); }
    inline int upper_bound(int x){
        x += MAXVAL;
        int c = mp[x];
        return (T.order_of_key((x*ADD)+c)); }
    inline void clear()
    {
        len = 0;
        T.clear();
        mp.clear();
    }
    inline int size() { return len; }
};
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int tests;
    cin >> tests;
    while (tests--)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        ordered_multiset Messi;
        long long nr = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int x;
            cin >> x;
            Messi.insert(x);
            nr += Messi.size() - Messi.upper_bound(x);
        }
        Messi.clear();
        cout << nr << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}


I've seen some solutions using MergeSort for an efficient solving, but I'm trying a different approach and would love some help with why my code isn't working.
My code works for their input, but it doesn't get accepted and I'm curious what's the issue with the program itself.
I apologise if it's poorly written/described , it's my first post here.

Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); is part of a cargo cult. Spaces and empty lines (creating paragraphs) make the code much easier to read. And any symbol starting with double underscore, unless specified in the C++ specification, should be considered internal and private.

Please note that "std::map is a sorted associative container", usually implemented as a red-black tree. So a perfect replacement for the custom tree class. Or, as a guess, perhaps what you want is std::set?

but I'm trying a different approach explain your approach please.

what is the meaning of "not working" ? "doesnt get accepted" does not help. You need to find a test case that fails. Then you can use a debugger to see where it fails. Then you can identify and understand the bug. Then you can fix it. But if you do not know what fails you cannot fix it.

did you write any tests? other than "their input" ?

I'm creating a set that allows duplicates in it and whenever I want to add an element, I see how many numbers in the set are already bigger than the one I'm adding. This is my approach and I've tried some different tests and they're all working properly, that's why I'm trying to get another perspectives cause I can't find the mistake by myself unfortunately, even after debugging it for hours.

I'm creating a set that allows duplicates...  C++ comes out-of-the-box with std::multiset.

you didnt manually type test cases by hand for hours, did you? For testing you should use hard coded input. Make sure to cover all corner cases, be creative, question all your assumptions, all of them. If you do not write repeatable tests you can continue for hours without finding the bug.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
